# Бесконечное switch case

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с вот такой вот проблемой. Создал класс, в нем проблем никаких нет и все работает как часы. В классе создал вот такую вот функцию.

```
    int users::enterMenu() {
    system("cls");
    char enterChoose;
    cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------  \n";
    cout << " |                 ВОЙДИТЕ В ПРОГРАММУ                     |  \n";
    cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------  \n";
    cout << " | 1-Пользователь.                                         |  \n";
    cout << " | 2-Администратор.                                        |  \n";
    cout << " | 3-Выход из программы.                                   |  \n";
    cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------  \n";
    do {
        fflush(stdin);
        enterChoose = _getch();

    } while (enterChoose > '4' || enterChoose < '1');
    return enterChoose;
}
```

Ну и я ее вызываю из main части программы, в конструкции cwitch case. Все выглядит так

```
users *ob = new users[25];
int sch = -1;
switch (ob->enterMenu()) {
case '1':
case '2':
{
    bool market = false;
    do {
        system("cls");

        char *username, *password, log_f[100], pass_f[100];;
        FILE *text;
        username = new char[100];
        password = new char[100];
        cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------  \n";
        cout << " |                ВВЕДИТЕ ЛОГИН И ПАРОЛЬ                   |  \n";
        cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------  \n";
        cout << " Имя пользователя: \n";
        cin >> username;
        cout << " Пароль:\n";
        cin >> password;
        if (((ob->enterMenu()) == 1)) { text = fopen("user.txt", "r"); }
        else { text = fopen("admin.txt", "r"); }
        while (!feof(text))
        {
            fscanf(text, "%s\t%s", log_f, pass_f);
            strcpy(password, md5(password).c_str());
            if (strcmp(log_f, username) == NULL&&strcmp(pass_f, password) == NULL) 
            {
                cout << " Поздравляем, вы вошли в систему!";
                market = true;
            }
        }
        if (market == false)
        {
            cout << " Ошибка! Проверьте правильность ввода данных!\n";
            cout << " Хотите повторите попытку ?";
            cout << " 1-Повторить";
            cout << " 2-Выйти";
            int in;
            cin >> in;
            if (in == 0)
            {
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        fclose(text);
    } while (market != true);


} 
case '3': exit(1);
}
```

Все проверки проходят! Но, суть проблемы в том, что когда например должно выдать *Поздравляем вы успешно вошли в систему!* он мильком выдает сообщение и опять возвращает в главное меню. В чем проблема. И как можно убрать. Что бы не выходило в обратное меню, а выдавало ответ, ну и там дальше можно было другие функции запускать. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

У вас по условию завершается цикл, но не свитч, и после второго `case` третий `case` соответственно выполняется всегда, вы выходите из текущего потока. 
Надо поставить туда `break;`, для завершения свитча после выполнения второго условия.
И после закрытия свитча выполнять желаемые функции.

Было бы хорошо, если бы вы выложили кусок main побольше - не понятно, есть ли там внешний цикл/поток, возвращающий обратно к выбору пункта меню.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри как делаю подобные [меню](https://github.com/whalemare/ProgLang.labs/blob/master/2%20%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-Polynomial/laba1/Main.cpp) я.

Возможно поможет чем-нибудь. Конкретно по твоему примеру: после всех case поставь break и, вероятнее всего, твой код заработает.

```
users *ob = new users[25];
int sch = -1;
switch (ob->enterMenu()) {
case '1':
   break;
case '2':
{
    bool market = false;
    do {
        system("cls");
    ....
break;
```